# Does Android have the iOS option 'application does not run in background'?

Tags: android, ios

I want to move from current page to login page in my app when clicking the Home Button (not recent button).

It is controlled by the option in iOS (application does not run in background to 'YES').

I don't know how to control it in Android.

I try this:

1. onDownKey (not working when clicking Home & Recent, but back button works well.)
2. onPause or onUserLeaveHint (I already controlled others in these methods, so I can't use it)
3. dispatchKeyEvent (also not working)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I control Home & Multi tasking button in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38994305/how-can-i-control-home-multi-tasking-button-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no direct equivalent functionality.  ANd you can't detect the home and recents button, the system handles them directly without ever passing them to your app.  Tell us why you want this behavior, and we may be able to help you.  But this would be extremely unusual behavior for Android.  In fact the exact opposite is what's usually the problem-  making sure you relaunch correctly if you're killed and relaunched via recents.

Comment: Thanks that kind of information!! First, when clicking only home button, I want to intent to Login Page in my App.(not the recent button)

and can I ask you where site which I see that information?? my boss want document... even if It is absolutely true..